# An algebraic structure with non-unique inverses?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is known that in groups, rings, and fields, the inverse of any element under the operations of the structure, provided it exists, is unique.  Can one define a set of elements, along with an operation, such that the inverse is NOT unique?  What properties would such a structure have?

Comment: Do you want inverses to exist for all elements?

Comment: @user26857 Two-sided inverses are unique. And if both left and right inverses exist, then they are equal. But it is also possible to have infinitely many of one type of inverse but none of the other, with associativity still present. This happens in the monoid of functions on an infinite set for instance (injective but not bijective implies left inverses but no right inverses, and surjective but not bijective implies right inverses but no left inverses).

Comment: I do not require the inverses to exist for all elements, no.

Comment: @arctictern: which linked page?

Comment: @user26857 I wasn't intending necessarily to start a discussion, just adding extra commentary since lack of associativity isn't the only source of nonuniqueness of inverses if one distinguishes left and right inverses. Since my examples are when associativity *is* present, it seems like it'd be out of place in the linked thread.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I am arctic tern. I never told you to go to any linked page. Rather, user26857 asked *me* to go to the linked page. Which is obviously the one this question is marked as a duplicate of.